# How to prove Lyapounov stability of a circle orbit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to go through exercises in V.Arnold's book on *Mathematical methods of classical mechanics.* There is a following exercise there: one considers a movement in a system with central potential

$\ddot{r}=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial r}, r=(x,y)$

Suppose $U(x)=(x^2+y^2)^{\alpha/2}=|r|^{\alpha}$. We will write $U(r)=r^{\alpha}$ and speak of $r$ as a radius to the origin. There is always a circle orbit: it corresponds to $r_0$ such that $U'(r_0)=\frac{M^2}{r_0^2}$ and $U(r_0)+\frac{M^2}{2r_0^2}=E$, $E$ and $M$ are energy and angular momentum -- quantities preserved along orbits. The question is for which $\alpha \in [-2, \infty)$ this circular orbit is Lyapounov stable. I know the answer: $\alpha=2$ but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: I will study this right now, to be able to solve it, and ask you marry me afterwards. Let's see how many of those I manage to get right.

Comment: I just learned the **Definition:** The DS is Lyapunov stable if we can get the whole solution arbitrarily close to the equilibrium by taking the initial condition close enough to the equilibrium.

Comment: $\alpha=2$ is the only system, which is linear. And for non-linear systems in questions it is true that the period of osculations  depends on the initial conditions.

Comment: @Artem still, they can be close to a circle, even if the period depends on initial conditions? $\alpha=2$ is a harmonic oscillator, orbits are ellipses

Comment: @ABC, the definition is correct. Although I know it. I won't ask a question without knowing what I actually want to obtain. That's also why you shouldn't ask me to marry you.

Comment: @Olga, Ok, now carefully read the definition of a solution to be Lyapunov stable and answer the question, why it is usually not used to define stability of closed curves.

Comment: @Olga Questions in which one knows what one wants to obtain are called exercises. Real questions have answers in the unknown, and their answers could be unexpected, enlightening. That is why they must be asked, without fear. As I said, I will try to solve the exercise and then ask the research question, in that order.